# The difference between np.mean and pandas.mean

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy.ma as ma

a = np.zeros((2,3,2))
a[0]=1
a[1]=3

a[0,0,1]=np.nan
a[0,1,1]=np.nan
a=ma.masked_invalid(a)
a
Out[17]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[[1.0 --]
  [1.0 --]
  [1.0 1.0]]

 [[3.0 3.0]
  [3.0 3.0]
  [3.0 3.0]]],
             mask =
 [[[False  True]
  [False  True]
  [False False]]

 [[False False]
  [False False]
  [False False]]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I want to get the result using `np.mean` like the following:

```
b = np.mean(a,axis=0)
b

Out[18]: 

masked_array(data =
 [[2.0 3.0]
 [2.0 3.0]
 [2.0 2.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

It ignores `NaN` values and reserve the masked array, when computing the average of array along `axis=0`.

But when I create a Panel using pandas and compute the average of the array:

```
p = pd.Panel(a)
b1=p.mean(axis=0)
b1.values
Out[25]: 
array([[ 2. ,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2. ]])
```

It seems that the mean method in pandas treats `NaN` values as zero and don't have masked array.

My question is how to get the same result using pandas as using `np.mean`?

Answer (score 0):

Build the panel as

```
p = pd.Panel(a.data)
```

Then you can get what you what:

```
In [334]: p.mean(axis=0)
Out[334]: 
   0  1
0  2  3
1  2  3
2  2  2
```

Comment: thanks It get the values of the array, but it don't include mask array . How can I get the mask array if I use pandas directly?